# Assignment in function argument list Javascript

Tags: javascript, arguments, anonymous-function

Is this valid JS? It runs but was wondering whether that was a browser quirk. I know its probably bad practice as its confusing but still a cool concept.

```
    showClickMask : function showClickMask(callback){

        (function(mask){
            mask.addClass('open');
            mask.click(function(){RAV.closeClickMask(mask,callback);});
        })(showClickMask.mask = showClickMask.mask || $('#click-mask'));

    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's valid, standards-compliant JavaScript.  Assignment is an expression, and "returns" the value being assigned.

(Whether you consider it good style is another question!)

Comment: Thanks; I think it is fine if I'm the only one using the library but probably a dick-move if working with a team.